# Dependency Injection в C# глазами Java разработчика

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Переучиваюсь с Java на C# и возник вопрос, связанный с внедрением зависимостей.

*IRepository.cs* - мой общий интерфейс для всех Entity-объектов, с которыми я хочу работать из базы данных.

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
    where T : class 
{
    void Create(T entity);
    T FindById(long id);
    ICollection GetAll();
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void DeleteById(long id);
}
```

*Account.cs* - обычный Entity-класс.

```
[Table("accounts")]
public class Account 
{

    public Account() 
    {
    }

    [Key, Column("id")] 
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column("email"), MaxLength(32)] 
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Column("registration_datetime"), Required]
    public DateTime Registration { get; set; }

    [Column("last_auth_datetime")] 
    public DateTime? LastAuth { get; set; }
}
```

*AccountRepository.cs* - мой класс с бизнес-логикой.

```
public class AccountRepository : IRepository<Account> 
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _dbContext;

    public AccountRepository(DatabaseContext dbContext) 
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
        
    public void Create(Account entity) 
    {
        _dbContext.Accounts.Add(entity);
    }

    public Account FindById(long id) 
    {
        return _dbContext.Accounts.Find(id);
    }

    public ICollection GetAll() 
    {
        return _dbContext.Accounts.ToList();
    }

    public void Update(Account entity) 
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete(Account entity) 
    {
        _dbContext.Accounts.Remove(entity);
    }

    public void DeleteById(long id) 
    {
        var tempAccount = FindById(id);
        if (tempAccount != null) 
        {
            Delete(tempAccount);
        }
    }
}
```

*DatabaseContext.cs* - класс по настройке EntityFramework Core.

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext {
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options) 
    {
    }

    #region Entities

    public virtual DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

*ServerStartHandler.cs* - Класс, который автоматически инициализируется во время запуска программы.

```
public class ServerStartHandler : AsyncResource 
{
    private readonly ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    private readonly AccountRepository _accountRepository;

    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public ServerStartHandler(AccountRepository accountRepository) 
    {
        _accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }

    public ServerStartHandler() : base(new ActionTickSchedulerFactory()) 
    {
        // read and build configuration
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .Build();
            
        // initialize dependency injection
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options
            .UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")));

        services.AddScoped<IRepository<Account>, AccountRepository>();
            
        // build DI services
        _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public override void OnStart() 
    {
        var getAllAccounts = _accountRepository.GetAll();
        Console.WriteLine($"Accounts count: {getAllAccounts.Count}");
        Console.WriteLine(">> Server started <<");
    }

    public override void OnStop() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(">> Server stopped <<");
    }
}
```

Но когда я хочу работать со своим AccountRepository.cs, то он null (как я понял, "инъекция" не прошла).

[image: Debug]

В Java (в частности, в Spring'е) было проще: просто создать Bean в конфигурационном классе, повесить аннотацию @Autowired, и "полетели". Тут немного сложнее для моего понимания.

Подскажите, может нужно что-то еще добавить? Или где-то я допустил ошибку, что мой объект не виден. Поделитесь любой информацией. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: `<IRepository<Account>, AccountRepository>` не уверено, но быть может вот так должно быть `<AccountRepository, IRepository<Account>>` или просто `<AccountRepository>`. Я просто с MS DI не работал.

Comment: @aepot Увы, не помогло. А с какими реализациями DI Вы работали? Может что-то посоветуете.

Comment: AccountRepository не до конца абстрагирован, вынести в базовый класс получение сущности _dbContext.Accounts и потом регистрировать как   `services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(RepositoryBase<>));` - одной строкой регистрировать все эти однообразные EntitynameRepository. Или написать обобщённый как тут: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.13.php

Comment: Это была попытка угадать. Я работал с Autofac и не в рамках ASP.NET Core (кстати, добавьте этот тег к вопросу). Вопрос весьма простой, наверняка вам что-то подскажут конкретное в ближайшее время.

Comment: А вообще ваш поход в настоящее время считается антипаттерном, гуглите статьи по запросам типа `c# antipattern generic repository`, например https://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/  https://developerslife.ru/8729

Comment: @aepot обязательно посмотрю в сторону Autofac, спасибо.

Comment: @AK благодарю за помощь в рефакторинге! Буду пробовать.

Comment: @alex я не сказал, что Autofac лучше, я просто сказал, что с MS DI у меня нет опыта. Насколько мне известно, оба IoC контейнера должны работать исправно.

Comment: Насколько я могу судить по беглому обзору вашего кода, зависимости регистрируются в классе `ServerStartHandler`. В то же время, сам этот класс принимает на вход зависимость (параметр конструктора). То есть в момент создания экземпляра этого класса зависимости уже должны быть зарегистрированы, где-то уровнем выше.

Comment: Если вы используете стандартный шаблон asp.net core приложения, то регистрируйте зависимости в методе `ConfigureServices` класса `Startup`.

Comment: На всякий случай ссылка на документацию: [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0). И если вы всерьёз берётесь за это дело, то книга Марка Симанна Dependency Injection (есть два издания; есть перевод на русский)